# Domain is redirected to another domain in same droplet

Tags: debian, apache-httpd

I am new on Debian, Built server on Digital Ocean with Debian OS.
I successfully added two domains into one droplet:

```
mysite.com
anothersite.com
```

Created new dir:

```
/home/user/www/mysite.com/public_html
```

and copied files to `public_html`

The config file inside `/etc/apache2/sites-available` is:

```
DocumentRoot /home/user/www/mysite.com/public_html

<Directory /home/user/www/mysite.com/public_html>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myproject-error.log
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myproject-access.log combined
```

Of Course, I enabled the site.

I haven't edited `apache2.conf` file and haven't configured 2nd domain (`anothersite.com`). Just added this 2nd domain to droplet, that's all.

When I enter to the site `mysite.com` it works perfect. Why is the 2nd domain (`anothersite.com`) redirected to the 1st (`mysite.com`) domain?

I use Apache 2.4

Comment: please post the entire `<VirtualHost>` of your apache config. and what exactly does *droplet* mean in this context?

Comment: droplet is just a symbolic name where you build your web server. Do you mean `000-default.conf` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a hostname (e.g. `anothersite.com`) point to the apache webserver but you haven't explicitely configured a `<VirtualHost>` section that matches that hostname, then apache will deliver a "best match" (the *first* ).

so if you only have a single `<VirtualHost>` in your apache config, and multiple hostnames (`mysite.com` and `anothersite.com`) point to the same machine, all of these names will display the *same* virtual host.

Comment: So, you mean if I have multiple domains I should have multiple VirtualHost? If yes, where it locates? Or you mean config files of each domain, which calls `mysite.com.conf`, `anothersite.com.conf` in `etc/apache2/site-available`?

Comment: it's best practice to have one snippet per vhost in your `/etc/apache/sites-enabled`, each prefixed with a number (so you *know* which one is the *first*); but you could also cram all of them into a single conf-file (or have all of the apache configuration in a single file) if you prefer it that way.